# Progressive JPEG layer/scan offsets (imagemagick?)

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, progressive

I've been searching high and low for this to no avail. I'd like to be able to extract the byte offset at which each progressive JPEG layer/scan occurs.

For example, let's say a 100 kB image has 5 layers used to render the final image; layer 1 ends at kB 5, layer 2 at kB 20, layer 3 at kB 60, etc (for example).

Is it possible to use Imagemagick for this? The `identify` tool does not seem to support doing so. If so, how? Otherwise what tool(s) could accomplish this? I'd rather not have to write a custom JPEG parser. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a progressive JPEG like this with **ImageMagick** for testing:

```
magick -interlace plane -size 400x200 gradient: progressive.jpg
```

`exiftool` will tell you quite a lot about it like this:

```
  exiftool -v3 progressive.jpg
```

**Sample Output**

```
  ExifToolVersion = 12.00
  FileName = progressive.jpg
  Directory = .
  FileSize = 2709
  FileModifyDate = 1620144585
  FileAccessDate = 1620144586
  FileInodeChangeDate = 1620144585
  FilePermissions = 33188
  FileType = JPEG
  FileTypeExtension = JPG
  MIMEType = image/jpeg
JPEG APP0 (14 bytes):
    0006: 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00       [JFIF..........]
  + [BinaryData directory, 9 bytes]
  | JFIFVersion = 1 1
  | - Tag 0x0000 (2 bytes, int8u[2]):
  |     000b: 01 01                                           [..]
  | ResolutionUnit = 0
  | - Tag 0x0002 (1 bytes, int8u[1]):
  |     000d: 00                                              [.]
  | XResolution = 1
  | - Tag 0x0003 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |     000e: 00 01                                           [..]
  | YResolution = 1
  | - Tag 0x0005 (2 bytes, int16u[1]):
  |     0010: 00 01                                           [..]
  | ThumbnailWidth = 0
  | - Tag 0x0007 (1 bytes, int8u[1]):
  |     0012: 00                                              [.]
  | ThumbnailHeight = 0
  | - Tag 0x0008 (1 bytes, int8u[1]):
  |     0013: 00                                              [.]
JPEG DQT (65 bytes):
    0018: 00 03 02 02 02 02 02 03 02 02 02 03 03 03 03 04 [................]
    0028: 06 04 04 04 04 04 08 06 06 05 06 09 08 0a 0a 09 [................]
    0038: 08 09 09 0a 0c 0f 0c 0a 0b 0e 0b 09 09 0d 11 0d [................]
    0048: 0e 0f 10 10 11 10 0a 0c 12 13 12 10 13 0f 10 10 [................]
    0058: 10                                              [.]
JPEG SOF2 (9 bytes):
    005d: 08 00 c8 01 90 01 01 11 00                      [.........]
  ImageWidth = 400
  ImageHeight = 200
  EncodingProcess = 2
  BitsPerSample = 8
  ColorComponents = 1
JPEG DHT (20 bytes):
    006a: 00 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
    007a: 00 00 04 08                                     [....]
JPEG SOS
JPEG DHT (19 bytes):
    0139: 10 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
    0149: 00 00 12                                        [...]
JPEG SOS
JPEG DHT (18 bytes):
    0468: 10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
    0478: 00 a0                                           [..]
JPEG SOS
JPEG DHT (20 bytes):
    048a: 10 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
    049a: 00 71 00 70                                     [.q.p]
JPEG SOS
JPEG SOS
JPEG DHT (21 bytes):
    0728: 10 00 03 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
    0738: 00 01 71 00 50                                  [..q.P]
JPEG SOS
JPEG EOI
```

---

You can also find the SOS markers like this:

```
xxd -c16 -g1 -u progressive.jpg | grep --color=always -A4 "FF DA"
00000070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 08 FF DA  ................
00000080: 00 08 01 01 00 00 00 01 D4 60 00 00 00 00 00 08  .........`......
00000090: 40 00 00 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 21 00 00  @............!..
000000a0: 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 00  ....B...........
000000b0: 00 01 08 00 00 00 00 00 02 10 00 00 00 00 00 04  ................
--
00000140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 12 FF DA 00 08  ................
00000150: 01 01 00 01 05 02 B5 AD 6B 5A D6 B5 AD 6B 5A D6  ........kZ...kZ.
00000160: B5 AD 6B 5A D6 B5 AD 6B 5A D6 B5 AD 6B 5A D6 B5  ..kZ...kZ...kZ..
00000170: AD 6B 5A D6 B5 AD 6B 5A D6 B5 AD 6B 5A D6 B5 AD  .kZ...kZ...kZ...
00000180: 6B 5A D6 B5 AD 6B 5A D6 B5 AD 6B 5A D6 B5 AD 6B  kZ...kZ...kZ...k
```

It may miss some markers if they fall across a 16-byte line end - I am still thinking about making this fool-proof. Maybe run it twice with a 4-byte offset so they can't fall on the boundary in both listings.

Alternatively, I did another answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1619035/363732) that lets you look for arbitrary binary sequences that you could easily adapt from looking for TIFF headers to looking for `FF DA`.

Answer (score 0):

All you'd have to do is scan the image stream and look for the SOS (Start of Scan) markers.

Comment: I figured I might have to do something like that. What's the best way to scan a binary file for a byte marker? I've never done that before.

Comment: You need to get a copy of the JPEG standard. All JPEG markers start with FF. Some of the markers have length fields that you have to use to skip over data that might include FF values. For the rest you scan for FF and simply skip the markers your are not interested in (including FF00, meaning a compressed FF value).

Comment: That's really useful. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

There is some php example code in this article by Christoph Erdmann:

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/08/faster-image-loading-embedded-previews/#creating-frontend-javascript-code

```php
$img = "progressive.jpg";
$jpgdata = file_get_contents($img);
$positions = [];
$offset = 0;
while ($pos = strpos($jpgdata, "\xFF\xC4", $offset)) {
    $positions[] = $pos+2;
    $offset = $pos+2;
}
```